# Getting some strange warnings when running hibernate-jpamodelgen Maven plugin

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, jpa-2.0, maven-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.1.1 with Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I’m using this goal to generate JPA meta data models …

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

However, when I run “mvn clean install”, I get all these warnings …

```
[INFO] javac option: -proc:only
[INFO] javac option: -processor
[INFO] javac option: org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor
[INFO] javac option: -d
[INFO] javac option: /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/core/target/classes
[INFO] javac option: -s
[INFO] javac option: /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/core/target/generated-sources/apt
[INFO] diagnostic /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/core/src/main/java/org/mainco/subco/myitem/queue/repo/MyItemDaoImpl.java:27:   cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MyItem_
location: package org.mainco.subco.myproj.queue.domain
[INFO] diagnostic /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/core/src/main/java/org/mainco/subco/assessment/dao/AssessmentDao.java:15: cannot find  symbol
symbol  : class SubItem_
location: package org.mainco.subco.secondproj.domain
[INFO] diagnostic /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/core/src/main/java/org/mainco/subco/secondproj/dao/SubItemDao.java:17: cannot find     symbol
symbol  : class NextItem_
```

Although my build ultimately completes just fine, I’m wondering how I can eliminate these warnings.